# Как подставлять произвольнные данные в пользовательский js

Tags: javascript, node.js, шаблонизаторы

Имею скрипт такого вида:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let allVideo = new window.VPlayer('192.168.1.67');
    /**
     * function (number, port, canvas_element, container)
     */
    allVideo.addVideo(0, 49002, $("#video-canvas-1").get(0), $('#jsmpeg1'));
    allVideo.addVideo(1, 49004, $("#video-canvas-2").get(0), $('#jsmpeg2'));
    allVideo.addVideo(2, 49006, $("#video-canvas-3").get(0), $('#jsmpeg3'));
    allVideo.addVideo(3, 49008, $("#video-canvas-4").get(0), $('#jsmpeg4'));

});
```

Данный скрипт является пользовательским. Выдавать его будет сервер express.js.
Особенность в том, что данные **'192.168.1.67'** и **4900*** меняются в зависимости от определенных причин. Вручную их править неудобно.
Поэтому решено автоматизировать это.
В теории это видится следующим образом: средства сборки **gulp\grunt** ищет произвольный шаблон, и заменяет его его данные полученные из конфигурационного json файла.

Весь вопрос сосоит в следующем:
 1. Подходит ли для текущих задач следующий плагин [gulp-jsfmt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsfmt)?
 2. Или существуют шаблонизаторы для js кода, на подобии handlebars и\или Mustache.js?
 3. Или стоит компановать этот код в handlebars и вставлять его на страницу при помощи хелпера? (похоже на костыль).
 4. Умеет ли TypeScript в такое? (Запрашивать данные для посдтановки перед преобразованием его в js)

**p.s.** запращивать эти данные с сервера при каждом подключении плохая идея. Хоть и не значительная, но лишняя нагрузка серверу.
**p.s.s.** формат записи скрипта корявый, и его можно записать более лаконично, но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: данные формируются динамически или один раз, при сборке проекта?

Comment: @Дмытрык, сейчас я его формирую вручную до сборки проекта. Но ничто не мешает его изменять непосредственно во время работы сервера

Comment: Если внедрять  код во время работы, то это уже SSR, если во время сборки, то можно придумать что-нибудь и без плагинов

Comment: @Дмытрык, я думал о кратком, самописном модуле делающем это. Но перед этим решил поискать, может быть это где-то уже реализовано в более простом варианте

Comment: Самое простое, подключить к странице js-файл... потом 2 варианта: 1) создать этот файл с нужными данными во время сборки 2) на запрос браузером этого файла отдать динамически сформированный контент

Comment: @Дмытрык, ну это то да. Это было самой первой мыслью :)

Comment: Вы предлагаете менять файл, я же, во 2-ом варианте, предлагаю отдавать динамический контент, можно даже без наличия, какого-либо шаблона